# Why "in" operator wasn't suitable here?

Tags: typescript

In attempt to make type which should be **values** of given object type I started with this:

```
type Book = {
  name:string,
  year:number,
  author:string
}

// expected result "string" | "number"
type ValueOf<T extends {}> = T[k in keyof T] // error due to "in"

let x:ValueOf<Book> ;
```

But seems `in` is redundant here. I could just have used `T[keyof T]`.

While I have seen `in` operator in similar cases like this:

```
type OptionsFlags<Type> = {
  [Property in keyof Type]: boolean;
};
```

Why wasn't it needed in my case? What concept did I miss related to `in` usage? What is rule of thumb when I could use `in`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### [Mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)

`in` should be used in mapped types such as the last type in your question:

```js
type OptionsFlags<Type> = {
  [Property in keyof Type]: boolean;
};
```

In mapped types, you are building a new `object` type through iteration:

```js
keyof Book = 'name' | 'year' | 'author'
OptionsFlags<Book> = {
  name: boolean;
  year: boolean;
  author: boolean;
}
```

#### [Indexed Access Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html)

Your `ValueOf` type is an indexed access type so you should remove the `k in`:

```js
type ValueOf<T extends {}> = T[keyof T];
```

In an indexed access type you are accessing the type of the value for the key you pass between angle brackets:

```js
type BookName = Book['name'] // string
```

But the key can also be an union type, which is the case of `keyof T`.

You may read this as "What types do I get when I go through all these key values?" (that would be a kind of projection in my mind). And with your `Book` type, Typescript would go through all these steps:

```js
ValueOf<Book>
=> Book[keyof Book]
=> Book['name' | 'year' | 'author']
=> Book['name'] | Book['year'] | Book['author']
=> string | number | string
=> string | number
```

Comment: in your example `OptionsFlags<Type>`, `in` is used within a property of an object right (`[Property in keyof Type]`)? In my example T is also an object, why I couldn't I use it there(as `T[in keyof T])`?

Comment: @john because it's not a mapped type.

Comment: yeah it seems I fail to see why my `ValueOf` is not mapped type, what does it lack? I also use indexed access inside it.

Comment: The curly braces to begin with.

Comment: A mapped type kinda iterates over its type parameters to generate an `object` type. Non mapped types don’t and the second example can be seen as a kind of projection. Let me try to add some more concrete example to my answer.

Comment: @john Did you read the page about the mapped type first ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler I didn't have enough time since this answer was posted, I had vague idea before, but its still bit blurry why my ValueOf isn't mapped type, so if Valentin adds just short info would be enough.

Comment: I added the non mapped type example.

Comment: @Valenting Ok I think should be enough I will accept this. Just I would appreciate if you can say what you meant with projection in above comment and which second example you referred to? Thanks

Comment: I edited it again with an explanation for mapped types.

Answer (score 1):

`in` in your example is for Mapped types.

What you want is :

```
type ValueOf<T extends {}> = T[keyof T] 

type foo =  ValueOf<Book> ; // string | number
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQg9nA1lAvFA3gKCjqA7AQwFsIAuKAZ2ACcBLPAcwBptcQIDry8BXIgIwjUWuKAR7AAFnC6Ua9BpgC%20mVaEhQAagQA2PCAHkAZgB4AKlAgAPYBDwATChiUA%20VFDMBtRBBBwjHgC6UGrg0EYI7lq6%20sYm8EhuANxQAPSpcnSMUAA%20%20HyC1EA)

---

A Mapped type is a generic type which uses a union of PropertyKeys (frequently created via a keyof) to iterate through keys to create a type. I mostly look like :

`{ [Property in keyof Type]: whatEverType; }`

Comment: I am curious why I couldn't use `T[k in keyof T]` ? Is my initial example (ValueOf) not mapped type?

Comment: @john `in` is part of the mapped type synthax ! This is not a valid mapped type.

Comment: yeah it seems I am trying to figure out why my ValueOf isn't mapped type